# If I use Jython can I simply edit it with a text editor for webpages?

Tags: jython

Right now, if I understand Python, not unlike PHP or even VBScript, etc., you can simply open a text editor, edit the code, run again.  This is particularly for webpages in my case.

With Java, don't you have to recompile everytime you make a change?  For example, if I need to add a condition to a method in one of my classes, don't I need to whip out the IDE and compile again?

It seems that with Jython I get the best of all, if I can do what I'm thinking, and assuming you like Python.

edit:  I just want to make sure I can do like I do now with a php page.  Open notepad, notepad++, or textmate, type in the new code, save, refresh webpage.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jython, being a flavor of Python, is an [*interpreted language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). As with all interpreted languages, you don't need to pre-compile the source code before running.

If you're looking for other interpreted languages for the Java Virtual Machine you might find these interesting:

- [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) (new iteration of JavaScript on the JVM—a successor for [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29))
- [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) (similar to Java, but more dynamic)
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) (a Lisp for the JVM)

Comment: Thanks.  I just want to make sure I can do like I do now with a php page.  Open notepad, notepad++, or textmate, type in the new code, save, refresh webpage.  Is that right?

Comment: Yup. But, it would probably be easier to just *try it* rather than posting a question and waiting for an answer!